# How to use ajax in Grails 3.2.3

Tags: ajax, grails, taglib, grails3, ajaxtags

I worked in grails 2.4.7 .Recently i shifted to grails 3.Previously i used grails custom tag for ajax call like remoteFunction, formRemote .This tags are not available for recent version.Can any one tell me the best way of using ajax for recent version .

Comment: Are you migrating code from 2.4.7 to 3 or starting a new project?

Comment: No .New project for grails 3 .

Comment: You can pull the old Grails ajax tag plugin behavior over with `compile 'org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0'` which i'd advise if migrating but if you're starting from scratch I'd implement yourself, is there a specific problem you're trying to solve or just generic question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from onward 2.4.x `g:remoteFunction` has been deprecated in grails.

See this. http://docs.grails.org/2.4.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Though, you can always use the javascript/jQuery ajax function as below which is exactly does the same thing.

```
<g:javascript>
  function callMyAjax(){
    $.ajax({ 
      url:'${g.createLink( controller:'yourcontroller', action:'youraction')}',
      data:{ 
           param1:param1,
           param2:param2
      }
    });
  }
 </g:javascript>

 <input type="button" onclick="callMyAjax()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, `ajax-tags` has been deprecated due to inefficiency issues. They recomend to **use Ajax or native javascript**.

Any way, if you still need them, there is a plugin for grails 3 provided as a migration library, but you can use it aswell:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0.RC1'
```